# Move Files from folder to another folder using name on mysql

Tags: php

Hi guys i have a website with 50 thousand pictures i have on my database all pictures name by Party_Id i have something like this

```
Picture_Id   |  Party_Id    |  Picture_Name
1            |  1           |  1aaaa.jpg
2            |  1           |  2aaaa.jpg
3            |  2           |  3aaaa.jpg
4            |  2           |  4aaaa.jpg
```

The problem when the website was created they put to save all the pictures on same folder, and now when you need to manipulate anything or access the folder is really crazy, the ftp cant display so many files.

so my idea was like  creat a folder for each party ID like 1, 2 , 3

then if possivel check on database for like select all the pictures where party id = 1 and move in folder 1, so then i can do one by one, and then delete or just keep the original folder.

i dont know how to do this, i really apreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you rephrase? What's your current PHP code now?

Comment: Hi @PraveenKumar like i said i dont have idea how to do this, i dont have any code actually, i know here is a place to get help ideas not for get the job done, i just asking maybe for a starting. thanks.

Comment: Okay, how do you get the folder names, when you say, a set of files are supposed to be inside a folder with a number? On what basis do you generate that number?

Comment: @PraveenKumar all the pictures are on a folder img/  on my database i have all pictures name with Party ID so on my idea i had to do something like this  Select Picture_Name from database Partys where Party_Id = 1. make a array with the pictures name, then Move all pictures from img/ to img/1/

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is, you have a Party ID and each Party has some set of pictures. So, insert the Party Details on the Database and you would be getting the ID of the generated party by using `last_insert_id()`.

Now, with that, you can normally upload the pictures by using, this way:

```
$target_path = "img/" . mysqli_insert_id();

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
```

So, do you feel this would be the right approach for your case? You will now have the directory structure this way:

```
img/
    1/
        photo_a_1.jpg
        photo_a_2.jpg
        photo_a_3.jpg
        photo_a_4.jpg
    2/
        bro_wedding_1.jpg
        bro_wedding_2.jpg
        bro_wedding_3.jpg
    3/
        birthday_1.jpg
        birthday_2.jpg
        birthday_3.jpg
        birthday_4.jpg
        birthday_5.jpg
```

Now you can use this way:

```
<img src="img/$partyId/$fileIndex" />
```

Comment: Yes but i dont want to upload @PraveenKumar i want to move the actual pictures. I alredy have the database with thousands pictures (about 100 for each Party) i want to do a code just to have the sctructure u did rightnow.

Answer (score 0):

I did like this and works, maybe not the best solution but did the job

```
  $Sql = "SELECT * FROM tabpartys WHERE Party_Id = '232'";
  $Query = mysql_query($Sql, $Conn) or die (mysql_error($Conn));
  while($Rs = mysql_fetch_array($Query)){
  // Identify directories
  $source = "../img/Fotos/".$Rs["Photo_Name"];
  $destination = "../img/Fotos/232/".$Rs["Photo_Name"];
  copy($source, $destination);
  }
```